# How to solve add_internal errors in pygame?

Tags: python, pygame

I have an issue with my code which mentions that 'Sprite' object has no attribute 'add_internal'. It's triggered from the `active_sprite_list.add` variable. I just wanted to know why does this error occur and how I can solve it. Here I have included the sprite class and the specific line where the error starts to happen.

```
class Sprite(object):
    def __init__(self, pos):
        super(Sprite, self).__init__()  # platform
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.platform = pygame.Surface((width, height))
        self.platform.fill(WHITE)
        # set a reference to the image rect
        self.rect = self.platform.get_rect()
        # Assign the global image to `self.image`.
        self.image = sprite_image

        # Create a rect which will be used as blit
        # position and for the collision detection.
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        # Set the rect's center to the passed `pos`.
        self.rect.center = pos
        self._vx = 0
        self._vy = 0
        # Assign the pos also to these attributes.
        self._spritex = pos[0]
        self._spritey = pos[1]
        # set of sprites sprite can bump against
        self.level = None


sprite = Sprite([400, 550])
level_list = []
level_list.append(Level_01)

# Set the current level
current_level_no = 0
current_level = level_list[current_level_no]

active_sprite_list = pygame.sprite.Group()
sprite.level = current_level

sprite.rect.x = 340
sprite.rect.y = H - sprite.rect.height
active_sprite_list.add(sprite)

# Loop until the user clicks the close button.
done = False

while not done:
    events()
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            done = True

        key = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if key == [pygame.K_RIGHT]:
            sprite.go_right()
        if key == [pygame.K_LEFT]:
            sprite.go_left()
        if key == [pygame.K_UP]:
            sprite.jump()
            # If the player gets near the right side, shift the world left (-x)
        if sprite.rect.right > W:
            sprite.rect.right = W

            # If the player gets near the left side, shift the world right (+x)
        if sprite.rect.left < 0:
            sprite.rect.left = 0

        current_level.draw(DS)
        active_sprite_list.draw(DS)
    # Call the `update` method of the sprite to move it.

    sprite.update()
    # Update the player.
    active_sprite_list.update()

    # Update items in the level
    current_level.update()

    DS.fill(BLACK)

    # Blit the sprite's image at the sprite's rect.topleft position.
    DS.blit(sprite.image, sprite.rect)

    pygame.display.flip()

    clock.tick(FPS)
```

---

*This is the code which triggers the current_level_update error where it requires a positional argument 'self' what shall i do to solve this error, this code will be placed after the sprite class in the full version of the code itself.
class Level_01(Level):
    """ Definition for level 1. """

```
def __init__(self):
    """ Create level 1. """

    # Call the parent constructor
    Level.__init__(self, Sprite)

    # Array with width, height, x, and y of platform
    level = [[210, 70, 500, 500],
             [210, 70, 200, 400],
             [210, 70, 600, 300],
             ]

    # Go through the array above and add platforms
    for p in level:
        block = platform(p[0], p[1])
        block.rect.x = p[2]
        block.rect.y = p[3]
        block.player = self.sprite
        self.platform_list.add(block)
```

Comment: Please try to turn your code into a [minimal, runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that contains only the code that's necessary to reproduce the error. Also, post the complete traceback. And make sure that your code is indented correctly (you can select it in the submission window and press Ctrl+K). The `key = pygame.key.get_pressed()` stuff and the lines below shouldn't be in the event loop.

Answer (score 3):

Your `Sprite` class must inherit from [`pygame.sprite.Sprite`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html) if you want to add it to a `pygame.sprite.Group`.

```
class Sprite(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, pos):
        # Don't forget to call the __init__ method of the parent class.
        super(Sprite, self).__init__()
```

---

Here's a complete example:

```
import pygame

pygame.init()

class Sprite(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, pos):
        super(Sprite, self).__init__()
        self.image = pygame.Surface((30, 50))
        self.image.fill((40, 60, 140))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.center = pos
        self._vx = 3  # The x-velocity.
        self._spritex = pos[0]
        self._spritey = pos[1]

    def go_right(self):
        # Update the _spritex position first and then the rect.
        self._spritex += self._vx
        self.rect.centerx = self._spritex

    def go_left(self):
        self._spritex -= self._vx
        self.rect.centerx = self._spritex


BLACK = pygame.Color('black')
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
display = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600))
sprite = Sprite([340, 550])
active_sprite_list = pygame.sprite.Group()
active_sprite_list.add(sprite)

done = False

while not done:
    # Handle events.
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            done = True

    # get_pressed() returns a list with the keys
    # that are currently held down.
    key = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    # Use pygame.K_RIGHT etc. as the index.
    if key[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
        sprite.go_right()
    elif key[pygame.K_LEFT]:
        sprite.go_left()
    if key[pygame.K_UP]:
        sprite.jump()  # Not implemented.

    # Update the game.
    # This calls the update methods of all contained sprites.
    active_sprite_list.update()

    # Draw everything.
    display.fill(BLACK)
    # This blits the images of all sprites at their rect.topleft coords.
    active_sprite_list.draw(display)

    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(30)
```

Instead of `pygame.key.get_pressed()` you could also use the event loop and check if a `pygame.KEYDOWN` event was produced and if it was `pygame.K_LEFT` or `K_RIGHT`, and then set the `_vx` attribute of the sprite to the desired value. The position could then be updated in the `update` method of the sprite.

Comment: Thank you for the help, should i now move the stuff from the key = pygame.get_pressed() to the class where I have defined the movement? Also, I've applied your changes and it now comes up with the error line 218, in <module>
    current_level.update()
TypeError: update() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

Comment: it now comes up with the error line 218, in <module> current_level.update() TypeError: update() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'  I'll add the relevant class to the error to see if you could help?

Comment: I think it would be better to post a new question, since this isn't related to the original question. Try to turn your code into a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that we can copy and run.